# What is the physical representation of peer in Fabric?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

In Fabric, we know the term of peers, [according to the docs](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.2/peers/peers.html), as

> a fundamental element of the network because they host ledgers and
>   smart contracts

Based on that, I assume that peers are some kind of hardware servers that organization assign.

But I'm not so sure about that, so I ask:

1. What exactly is the physical representation of peers in real-case organization?
2. Is it a computer that must always be online? Is it operated by some person in the related organizations?

It is also said in [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.10228.pdf) on page 6 about the consensus process, that

> In particular, this **requires all endorsers**
>   as determined by the policy to produce the same execution result
>   (i.e., identical readset and writeset). Then, the client proceeds to
>   create the transaction and passes it to the ordering service

This leaves me to the next question:

3. In real life usage, if the endorsing peers failed temporarily (say, due to electricity issue), does it mean that the blockchain transactions can't happen in that time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A peer is a software service. An organization can have multiple peers running for resilience. When a peer fails, for whatever reason, when it is restarted, it will catch up with the other peers in an organization's cluster either by receiving missing transaction blocks from the orderer, or by gossiping with other peers.

If an endorsing peer fails, it does not necessarily mean that the transaction processing will be blocked. Again, an org can have multiple redundant endorsing peers, and depending on the endorsement policy chosen for the channel, propose the transaction to other endorsing peers for that channel in order to receive the requisite number of endorsements to satisfy the policy.

Of course, if you ran a single endorsing peer for a channel/network... then yes, if it failed then transaction processing would be blocked. That would not be a wise deployment choice;-) Fabric was designed for resilience.

Comment: Would you care to elaborate more about peer as a "software service"? Thank you!

Comment: It is a process that runs in an operating system. In the case of Fabric, inside a Docker container.

Comment: @christo4ferris Must this process running in the Docker container be always "on" in the sense of being always active? My question comes from the attempt to understand if it's possible, and makes sense, to have peers in, for examples, laptops, tablets and smartphones, just when the connect to the fabric's network